# Add key value to an array elements in JS

Tags: javascript

I can't add a key value pair to my array objects:

```
 const arr = [{'a' :1, 'b':2},{'a':2, 'b':4}]
 arr.map( item => {item.price = 1
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += 'a : '+ item.price + ' ' });
```

I want arr to be :

```
{'a' :1, 'b':2, 'price' : 1},{'a':2, 'b':4, 'price' : 1}
```

Comment: getElementById("body") ??

Comment: Why are you using `document` if you only want to edit the array?

Comment: I was trying to display the result, It's not the problem, consider it a console.log..

Comment: `map` needs to return a new item. `item.price = 1` will amend the incoming item, and then return `1`, making the array `[1,1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map function doesn't modify the array you do it to, it returns a new modified array. So you must assign the output to a variable. I would suggest reading a bit more how mapping arrays works on the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Here's how I would implement what you're looking for:

```js
const arr = [{'a' :1, 'b':2},{'a':2, 'b':4}];
const newarr = arr.map( item => ({ ...item, price: 1 }) )
```